# How does deep link URI works on iOS?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

travelbrand://hotel/123

this is an example of deep link URI; where to tell my app that the word "hotel" means the view controler which contains the hotels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When someone taps a link and the OS routes it into your app, one of two methods in your `UIApplicationDelegate` will be called.

1. If the app is already running, then the method will be

`- application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`

where the `url` parameter will be the `NSURL` that brought the user there.

2. If the app is cold started, then the method will be

`- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

and the `launchOptions` parameter will contain a key called `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` for which the value will be the `NSURL` that was used to launch the app.

In either case, you end up with an `NSURL` which you can parse either manually by getting the `absoluteString` and doing string manipulation on it, or by using something like `NSURLComponents`.

a `NSURLComponents` solution for your URL might look like:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
NSString *scheme = components.scheme; // travelbrand
NSString *host = components.host; // hotel
NSString *path = components.path; // /123
```